# Flurry and Phonegap for Android: How to use onPageView

Tags: android, cordova, analytics, flurry

has anyone experiences to track the viewing pages in Phonegap App for android with Flurry?

Right now i have to use events. But it makes me unable to view the user path in Flurry Dashboard. Because phonegap app has typically only 1 actvitiy, so it's also not ok when i call  Flurry.onPageView() in my main activity.

There is should be a way to custom the name of the page so that i can track the viewing page event with Flurry.